# Join 2 tables with different values/columns

Tags: sql

I have 2 tables that records sales data

Table A has sales data for this year, and table B has sales target data for the year. Table A's data most recent data is the previous day (actual sales data) while table B has target data throughout the whole year.

What I want to do is basically join both tables data where I can see sales data and target data in 1 table. Using my example below, I'd want 1 row to read.

Date | Geo Agg | State | City | Neighborhood | Total Sales | Target Sales

If the date is in the future, total sales would be null.

The main issue I'm having is that Table A (actual sales data) has data with neighborhood granularity, while Table B (target sales data) does not.

Table A has the following columns

- Date
- Geo_Aggregation (inputs are State, City, Neighborhood)
- State
- City
- Neighborhood
- Total Sales

and Table B has the following columns

- Date
- Geo_aggregation (inputs are State, City)
- State
- City
- Target Sales

I've tried a full outer join but it breaks because I cant join on geo_aggregation due to Table B not having a Neighborhood aggregation, or neighborhood column.

If I'm using Los Angeles as an example, and lets say Los Angeles only has 2 neighborhoods. I'd like the output table to read ...

| Date | geo_agg | State | city | neighborhood | total_sales | target_sales |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 11/5/2023 | Neighborhood | California | Los Angeles | Santa Barbara | $50 | $150 |
| 11/5/2023 | Neighborhood | California | Los Angeles | Hollywood | $502 | $150 |
| 11/6/2023 | Neighborhood | California | Los Angeles | Santa Barbara | $502 | $150 |
| 11/6/2023 | Neighborhood | California | Los Angeles | Hollywood | $502 | $150 |
| 11/7/2023 (Today) | Neighborhood | California | Los Angeles | Santa Barbara | $502 | $150 |
| 11/7/2023 (Today) | Neighborhood | California | Los Angeles | Hollywood | $502 | $150 |
| 11/8/2023 (Pretend this is a future date) | Neighborhood | California | Los Angeles | Santa Barbara | Null | $150 |
| 11/8/2023 (Pretend this is a future date) | Neighborhood | California | Los Angeles | Hollywood | Null | $150 |

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Does it require an extension for geographic data? Please supply the names and versions you are using.

Comment: What exactly is the join criteria you want? It's not obvious from the question (date and geo aggregation I suppose?). What exactly is the format of the `Geo_Aggregation` fields? It would be better if you showed an example of data the the 2 joined tables that correspond to your requested result

Answer (score 0):

I cannot be sure that you need a fuill outer join, that depends on the extent to which the 2 tables differ and exactly what you want from the query. Nevertheless you can use it without involving `Neighborhood` in the join conditions, but this will cause TableB values to repeat over matched TableA rows (as seen in your example above for the $150).

```
SELECT
      COALESCE(A.DATE, B.TDate) AS DATE
    , COALESCE(A.STATE, B.STATE) AS STATE
    , COALESCE(A.City, B.City) AS City
    , A.Neighborhood AS Neighborhood
    , A.Total_Sales AS Total_Sales
    , B.Target_Sales AS Target_Sales
FROM TableA A
FULL OUTER JOIN TableB B ON A.DATE = B.TDate AND A.STATE = B.STATE AND A.City = B.City
```

The "wildcard" might be the date column as there may be many mismatched rows if the 2 tables have different dates.

An alternate approach would be to aggregate TableA up to the same level of granularity as TableB - but again I'm not sure what you are trying to achieve.